# Host cannot connect to Internet but Guest VMs can

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, bridge

I don't know if this is a question is more suited for this site or askubuntu, but here's my situation:

Running 18.04 Ubuntu and I made a bridged interface to allow my VM to share the connection. Now I don't now how `/etc/network/interfaces` works but my guess is that it defines interfaces(physical or virtual). Much to my surprise, the VM is able to fetch packages from the internet, but my host cannot anymore. The host still has local connectivity to my LAN and also pings 8.8.8.8 but that's about it. I gui'd into the server and saw that ethernet option is missing from settings. I'm not sure why this happened. In my `/etc/network/interface` file I removed the entry for `enp3s0` and replaced it with `br0`. Is that how networking is supposed to work? Here is the file.

******* current config *********

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback   

auto br0
     iface br0 inet static
         address 192.168.0.108
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         gateway 192.168.0.1

         #broadcast 192.168.0.255
         dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
         # set static route for LAN
            #post-up route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.18.44.1
            #post-up route add -net 161.26.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 10.18.44.1
         bridge_ports enp3s0
         bridge_stp off
         bridge_fd 0
         bridge_maxwait 0
```

******* previous config *********

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.108
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8. 8.8.4.4
```

Is my internet not working because I completely removed "enp3s0" which is my physical interface from this file? But that can't be true because I can still ssh into the machine and ping 8.8.8.8. What exactly is happening?

Comment: It was unexpectedly a dns issue. I checked `/etc/resolv.conf` and found the nameserver had changed to 127.0.0.53. Not sure why that happened but adding google's dns server address did fix the problem. Can anybody tell me why this happened? Does 127.0.0.53 have any significance?

Comment: It did. Restarting networking reverted dns back to 127.0.0.53 and now I have to manually change it back to 8.8.8.8 before I can use the internet. What is a permanent fix?

Comment: Sure. I'll post another question although this is a similar one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012641/dns-set-to-systemds-127-0-0-53-how-to-change-permanently

Answer (score 1):

The issue it turns out that for some reason `systemd-resolved` kept editing `/etc/resolvd.conf` nameserver entry to `127.0.0.53`. Manually changing that to a working DNS server did resolve the issue, however on networking service restart/system reboot the issue returned.
To fix from that happening run:

```
systemctl stop systemd-resolved
```

and

```
systemctl mask systemd-resolved
```